# Question about the closed set

Tags: general-topology

Is there a topological space on $\mathbb{R}$ in which the interval $(0,1)$ or intervals like $(a,b)$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the discrete topology, where every subset of $\mathbb R$ is open (hence every subset of $\mathbb R$ is closed as well).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if all you require to be closed is $(0,1)$, you can even make it homeomorphic to the usual topology on $\mathbb R$.

Since $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ have the same cardinality, you can select a bijection $f:(0,1)\to[0,1]$.
Similarly select a bjection $g:\mathbb R\setminus(0,1)\to\mathbb R\setminus[0,1]$.

Then $$h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x) & x\in (0,1) \\ g(x) & x \notin (0,1) \end{cases}$$
is a bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Now consider the topology where $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ is open if and only if $h(A)$ is open in the *usual* topology. Then $(0,1)$ is closed in this topology because $h((0,1))=[0,1]$